# How to solve a two BJT circuit?

Tags: voltage, resistors, bjt, current-measurement

Please could someone help me understand how to solve this circuit?[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Is this homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you! It was a problem I was having my doubts with how to solve it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF that is your hand-writing, may I complement you on artistic expression and sense of scale.

Unfortunately , I can barely print my own name after recent surgery from a random event called hand Ischemia with TOS bypass and nerve damage. So I resort to a quick mouse drawn simulation.

[image]

Since this is just a two stage emitter follower, the best you can hope for is unity gain and DC bias not to screw up the signal.  Unfortunately Q2 hFE has a significant effect on the input impedance and resulting 16k voltage divider effects.

Can you [read](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.000005%2016.13108636308289%2060%2015%2053%0Aw%20240%2048%20336%2048%201%0Ar%20240%2048%20240%20208%200%2039000%0At%20272%20208%20336%20208%200%201%20-0.097251713462299%200.5569169633026902%2020%0AR%20240%2048%20144%2048%200%200%2040%2020%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20336%2048%20336%20160%200%202200%0Ar%20368%20224%20400%20224%200%2016000%0Ac%20240%20208%20160%20208%200%205e-7%2019.47788606016831%0AR%20160%20208%20112%20208%200%201%20200%200.5%200%200%200.5%0AO%20432%20240%20480%20240%200%0Ar%20432%20272%20432%20320%200%201200%0Ag%20432%20320%20432%20352%200%0At%20400%20224%20432%20224%200%201%20-4.918435918110527%200.6593633959447285%2050%0Aw%20336%2048%20432%2048%201%0Aw%20432%2048%20432%20208%200%0Aw%20240%20208%20272%20208%202%0Aw%20432%20240%20432%20272%202%0Aw%20336%20192%20336%20160%202%0Ax%20292%20258%20416%20261%204%2016%20Zin%5CqhFE*Re%5Cs%5Cs%5Cq%5Cq%3E%0Aw%20368%20224%20336%20224%202%0Ao%207%2064%200%204354%200.625%200.00009765625%200%202%207%203%0Ao%208%2064%200%2012546%2014.888958518087826%200.0001%201%201%0A) the resulting DC out and AC Vpp attenuation?

Then figure it out.

Left is input, right trace is output.  hFE1=20, hFE2=50

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: So how did you compute Ve2 output dc bias?

Answer (score 0):

As you are given the \$\small \beta \$ values for both BJT's, there is, effectively, only one unknown in the circuit. Let this be the base current of the first BJT, \$\small I_{B1}\$, then apply KVL to the path: \$\small 39k/V_{BE1}/16k/V_{BE2}/1.2k\$

Assuming \$\small V_{BE1,2}=0.7\:V\$, gives: \$\small I_{B1}=11\:\mu A \$; \$\small I_{CQ2}=11.55\:mA\$

Comment: Not showing the internal steps isn't helping anyone.  But perhaps the op took your answer and handed in his home work already.

Comment: @Nedd Firstly, the reason I didn't give the 'internal steps' is precisely because it's homework. Secondly, the reason I gave the answer is because Tony Stewart had already uploaded a simulation which contained the answer. Please check carefully before uploading criticism.

Answer (score 0):

Transistors have a fairly wide range of hFE and you do not know the hFE unless you buy thousands and test and sort them. Therefore that simple circuit is never used.
The 2.2k collector resistor and base resistor R1 in it are usually not needed.

Comment: Lots of transistors used in consumer products are sold with binned hFE (designated by a suffix letter, so you order the range you want) that has a narrow enough range for fixed  bias in some applications. Eg. C2712Y has a range of 120~240. It’s generally discouraged, but the numbers can work so it’s quite practical in some applications.